# Function to return the address to a row of values from a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm at my wit's end here, my friends.

The purpose of this function is to take in a pointer to 2D array, a row number, and a column size and return the address that points to a specified row of values in a 2D array. I'm not sure how to accomplish this, any advice?

Thanks in advance.

```
double* get_row(double *the_array, int row_num, int col_size) {
cout << "Get Row : "<< the_array[row_num]<< "\n";
return the_array+row_num;}
```

The reason for the cout is to confirm that it's the right set of values I'm returning a pointer to but I'm not exactly sure I've implemented that correctly.

EDIT:

Here is the full code

```
#include "TwoDArray.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */

void set_row(double *the_array, int row_num, int col_size, double *row_vals) {
    for (int i = 0; i < col_size; i++)
        the_array[i] = *row_vals + i;
    cout << "Set Row:"<< *the_array << "\n";
}

double get_element(double *the_array, int row_num, int col_size, int col_num) {
    double thisElement = (*(the_array + (row_num * col_size)) + col_num);
    return thisElement;
}

double* get_row(double *the_array, int row_num, int col_size) {
    cout << "Get Row : "<< the_array[row_num]<< "\n";
    return the_array+row_num;
}

double sum(double *the_array, int row_size, int col_size) {

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < row_size; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < col_size * row_size; i++) {
            sum += the_array[i] + j;

        }
        return sum;
    }
}

double find_max(double *the_array, int row_size, int col_size) {
    double max_so_far = the_array[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < row_size; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < col_size * row_size; i++)
            if (the_array[i] + j > max_so_far)
                max_so_far = the_array[i] + j;
    return max_so_far - 1;
}

double find_min(double *the_array, int row_size, int col_size) {
    double min_so_far = the_array[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < row_size; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < col_size * row_size; i++)
            if (the_array[i] + j < min_so_far)
                min_so_far = the_array[i] + j;
    return min_so_far;


}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    const int row_size = 2; //i
    const int col_size = 3; //j
    double B[2][3] = {
        {68, 2, 44},
        {7, 8, 3}
    };
    double (*p)[3] = B;
    double C[2][3] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 2, 3}};

    double (*f)[3] = C;

    cout << "\n" << "Sum of all Elements = " << sum(*p, 2, 3) << "\n"; ///Expected: 132
    cout << "\n" << "Get Element = " << get_element(*p, 1, 0, 0) << "\n"; //Expected: 68
    cout << "\n" << "Largest Element = " << find_max(*p, 2, 3) << "\n"; //Expected: 68
    cout << "\n" << "Smallest Element = " << find_min(*p, 2, 3) << "\n"; //Expected: 2
    cout << "\n" << "Get Row = " << get_row(*p, 0, col_size) << "\n"; //Expected: 2
    set_row(*p, 2, 3, *f);
    cout << "\n" << B[2][3];
    cout << "\n";



}
```

Comment: It depends how you are representing your 2D array. It is an array of arrays or is it a single array containing each row sequentially? Your function arguments seem to imply the latter, but your implementation seems to imply the former.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: _"but I'm not exactly sure I've implemented that correctly."_ That's what test cases are for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm representing an array of arrays.

Comment: `double (*p)[3] = B;` is simply a pointer to the first row of `B`. You then proceed to use it as if it pointed to the entire array. This might work for now because of the way you've allocated your array (as a `double [2][3]`) but it won't hold if you transit to dynamic allocation. It only works because each row happens to be allocated sequentially. In reality you should be passing `B` around and treating it as a `double **` when it decays to a pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So from what I understand you mean I should be testing with say `&B[row_size][col_size]` instead of `*p`?

Comment: If you simply give `B`, it will decay to a pointer. `double[][]` decays to `double**` implicitly.

Comment: Consider using [`std::array<std::array<double>, 2>, 3>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector<std::vector<double>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to represent your array instead of C arrays. They are simpler and more intuitive to use.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Weird, I tried just passing `B` through the functions but it gives me an error. Says `TwoDArray.cpp:89:61: error: cannot convert 'double (*)[3]' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'double find_max(double*, int, int)' `. It works fine though when I do `&B[2][3]` or `*p`.

Comment: You've neglected the first advice I gave, which is to use `double**` for your function parameters that refer to the array. Re-reading it, it may have been unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x + y * col_size` gives a 1D index of the array when `x` and `y` are 2D array coordinates. So to access the first element of a row you would set `x = 0` and `y = row_num`. Than just return the address of your element.

```
return &the_array[row_num * col_size];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar code I've been using on 1D representations of matrices, maybe this will help

```
// 2D to 1D
int get_index(int x, int y)
{
    return y*WIDTH + x;
}

// 1D to 2D
int get_x(int index) { index % WIDTH; }
int get_y(int index) { index / WIDTH; }
```